# Is there any way to declare a function that can take both an int and a double as it's argument in MQL4?

Tags: function, types, mql4, metatrader4, mql5

I have these two functions:

```
void CheckOneConditionInt( int    &SettingsEditValueInt );
void CheckOneConditionDbl( double &SettingsEditValueDbl );
```

They do the same stuff, but one is used with **`int`** values and another is used with **`double`** values. Is there any way to make it one function that can take int/double as an argument? For example:

```
void CheckOneCondition( void &SettingsEditValue );
```

PS: The example does not work of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by using templates:

```
template<typename T>
void CheckOneCondition( T &SettingsEditValue );
```

I can then call it passing `double` or `int` parameter.

Comment: Still, as noted in my answer few days ago, **there is not any problem defined** ( no use-case ), **where such artificially amorphous behaviour would be both a must + un-avoidable by other, available, means** of the MQL4/5 syntax tools. **If there is any such, be so kind and post it.** Thank you in advance.

Comment: The use-case is applying the same algorithm to values of both `double` and `int` type.

Comment: If this were indeed the only case, the type-cast is the appropriate tool, no artificial complexities, no OOP, no overloading paradigms. Simply making a call to a single function, with a `double`-expecting calling interface **`aFun( (double)anIntVALUE ... );`** This is exactly what type-casting was designed and is available for.

Comment: It does not seem to work when the parameter is passed as a reference. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea. The mechanics of passing a value byRef is completely another story.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about method overloading? It is used in MQL4.5.
So, if you pass int value then `Function( int value )` is called, if real - then `Function( double value )` is called. If the algorithm applied to both types is same - maybe you can just skip `Function( int value )`, or add a wrapper inside the integer function, something like:

```
Function( int &value ){
   double tmp = value/1.0;       
   Function( tmp );
   value = ( int ) Normalize( tmp, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea about using a wrapper. Still I would prefer to know if MQL4/5 offers a more elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: One ought realise the shorthandiness of the proposal. Passing an `int` does not provide means for fractions to be passed to the processing part of the `Fun( int &byRef ){...}`, which is a principal deformation to the proposed idea. A reverse design, to pass `double` could process also the `int`-s typecast as an external responsibility to a `double`. Still, as noted in my answer, there is not any **problem** defined ( no use-case ), where such artificially amorphous behaviour would be both a must + un-avoidable by other, available, means of the MQL4/5 syntax tools. If there is any such, post it

Comment: Of course, I would implement it as `Function( double &value )`. My use-case is rather simple. The algorithm for processing the doubles and ints in the functions the same. So repeating it twice makes no sense.

Comment: If you do not like wrapper, there is one more way - use generics. do not know what to show here, just go to [link](https://docs.mql4.com/en/basis/oop/templates) to see an example. There's some other way of assigning which function to use, but i do not remember how to find it and never used it. Hope 'mql template' is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes and No.

While the *New*-**`MQL4.56789`** extensions have introduced classes ( inside which there are means for multiple calling interfaces ( where one could being suited for **`double`** and another for **`int`** ), which could mean **YES** ),
the **`MQL4`** is in its initial design principles a compiled language with strong typing,
which means **NO**.

---

### Design decision rules

A sound and clear desing can answer the dilemma. There is no principal reason to have ambiguous, dual-typed calling interface in MQL4 problem domain.

Except for some theoretical experimentation, there is always a deterministic certainty, of what type the value to be passed to a function is, thus an amorphous dual-(multi)-typed calling interface is moreless an academical subject in MQL4 context of use.

---

### Epilogue

> If one indeed seeks for such an extremely artificial geekiness to achieve such non-deterministic agnosticism, let's first define a clear MQL4-domain use-case, for which such uncertaintiness of parameter type is both necessary and un-avoidable by other, available, means.

Comment: I'll take that as a No.

Comment: Which means in plain english **there is no such use-case to be shown** as an indeed un-avoidable need-to-have an amorphous / polymorhphic calling interface in MQL4 , doesn't it?